# How can I find the IP of a shared iTunes library on our network?

Tags: windows, networking, itunes, network-shares

How can I find the IP address of a computer with a shared iTunes library?  The share shows up in iTunes, but it's with an odd name on a largish network and I need to know which computer is sharing the library.

Answer (score 2):

[Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/) will give a list of all Bonjour services on your network. It will list all the computers with their names, IP address and ports. Mac OS X only.

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal:

```
lsof | grep iTunes | grep TCP
```

Comment: How 'bout from a PC?

Comment: I do have access to a mac, but I couldn't get the share to show up on the mac.

Answer (score 1):

You want a ZeroConf/Bonjour browser which allows you to see the packets sent out by iTunes.

Under Windows I would suggest the Zeroconf Neighborhood Explorer - http://www.stg.com/zeroconf_explorer.html

If you have a programmer near, there is a very helpful demo program in the jmdns project (Java based)